# Toolbar logo taking up too much space

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Im dealing with a strange toolbar behavior in which if I set a logo with

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo_toolbar);
```

The Toolbar components (in my case the logo itself and the title) get disaligned from the standard gravity start behavior.

This is my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/grey_900"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

The toolbar has a SearchView at the right and no "home button", only title.

Graphic explanation:

1) Behavior without calling `setLogo(...)`

2) Behavior when calling `setLogo(...)`

3) What I'm trying to achieve

[image: Explanation]

I've already tried playing with gravity but nothing happened.
Also, please, I know that `Toolbar` is a ViewGroup and I can customize it, but I'm looking for a clean code, also this should be a default behavior and but it isn't working so I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, if you add icon programmatically with toolbar options automatically appears the "big space" because toolbar need that space for "burger icon" which open the 'navigation drawer' , you can add a `ImageView` when you want and assign the image to this `ImageView`, programmatically too if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

If you use getSupportActionBar , No need to use toolbar again.